# ¿Porque en C# los dataGridView no pueden contener una primary key de autoincremento por mucho tiempo?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Al seleccionar algun registro de mi dataGridView selecciona todos correctamente pero al llegar a la celda del registro que contiene la primary key me lo toma como NULL y me muestra un error porque no contiene nada,¿Que tengo que hacer para que me muestre la primary key?

```
private void btnElegir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClassBT.clsProducto.NOMBRE = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            ClassBT.clsProducto.MONTO_POR_SERVICIO = int.Parse(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            ClassBT.clsProducto.NUMERO_DE_CLIENTE = int.Parse(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());

            this.Close();
        }
```

NOTA: solo me da error en el Numero de cliente que es autoincremental en los otros no.

Comment: Recuerda, que en c# la primera posición es la 0, por lo que si pones cells[3], estas accediendo a la celda 4

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: agregando a lo que dijo Japv.. el numero de cliente en que columna esta?

Comment: Muchas gracias, si era ese el error, el numero de cliente estaba en la columna 3 osea en c# en la 2 y ya me corre bien el programa, MUCHAS GRACIAS!!!